# Javascript find if an object has at least one non undefined property

Tags: javascript

I was wondering between those two methods, which one would be faster and why?

Using **Object.values** and [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty)

```
isOneObjectPropertyNonUndefined(object) {
    let isObjectEmpty = true;
    if (!lodash.isEmpty(object)) {
      const objectValues = Object.values(object);
      for (let index in objectValues) {
        if (objectValues[index] !== undefined) {
          isObjectEmpty = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  return isObjectEmpty;
}
```

Using **JSON.stringify**

```
isOneObjectPropertyNonUndefined(object) {
    return JSON.stringify(object) === '{}';
}
```

Behind JSON.stringify it might be some C/C++ code. If it is a valid fact, is it ok to assume it's faster ?

**EDIT** : Seems like JSON.stringify is faster with jsperf.
https://jsperf.com/test-one-object-field-non-undefined/1
Even though it's tested with only one very simple input.

Comment: Have you tried them? Gathered some empirical evidence. Or to put it another way, you have 2 horses. Race them.

Comment: `return JSON.stringify(object) === {}` makes no sense, did you miss the quotes?

Comment: [Obligatory link to Eric Lippert's rant on performance](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)...

Comment: https://jsperf.com/ Figure it out

Comment: @epascarello I'll try with jsperf (missed the quotes ty)

Answer (score 3):

Those both seem way more complicated than necessary:

```
isOneObjectPropertyNonUndefined(object) {
    return Object.values(object).some(v => v !== undefined));
}
```

That will return `true` if the object has at least one property whose value is not `undefined`, `false` if it has no properties or they all have the value `undefined`.

That's for "own" properties (just like `JSON.stringify`).